# What does the security implications for default character set in mysqli_real_escape_string() means?

Tags: php, security, mysqli

In PHP documentation for mysqli_real_escape_string(), it is written that

> Caution 
>   **Security: the default character set**
>
> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the
>   API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect
>   mysqli_real_escape_string().

Source [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

In a further link about character set, it is mentioned that

> The character set should be understood and defined, as it has an
>   affect on every action, and includes security implications.

Suource [Character sets](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php)

Why does it necessary to set the character set for the sake of security and what security implications does it include?
Can anyone, explain the concept behind those lines ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what needs to be escaped is Character set dependent

Comment: @Dagon - What does it even mean ?

Comment: not sure how to be clearer - if you look at the php source the Character's that are escaped, is dependent on the Character set used. What is escaped in *latin1* is not the same as what is escaped in *utf8* so the function needs to know what is being used

Comment: ok but what does it matter in terms of security ?

Comment: unescaped strings can lead to my(sql) injection attacks

Comment: Ok, You are trying to say, that if one do not specify the character set, the argument of the function would not be escaped which could leads to mysql injection, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How SQL queries are parsed is dependent on the connection character set. If you did this query:

```
$value = chr(0xE0) . chr(0x5C);
mysql_query("SELECT '$value'");
```

then if the connection character set was Latin-1 MySQL would see the invalid:

```
SELECT 'à\'
```

whereas if the character set were Shift-JIS, the byte sequence 0xE0,0x5C would be interpreted as a double-byte character:

```
SELECT '濬'
```

Add string literal escaping for security:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
mysql_query("SELECT '$value'");
```

Now if you've correctly set the connection character set to Shift-JIS with `mysql_set_charset`, MySQL still sees:

```
SELECT '濬'
```

But if you haven't set the connection character set, and MySQL's default character set is Shift-JIS but PHP's default character set is ASCII, PHP doesn't know that the trailing 0x5C character is part of a double-byte sequence, and escapes it, thinking it is generating the valid output:

```
SELECT 'à\\'
```

whilst MySQL reads it using Shift-JIS as:

```
SELECT '濬\'
```

With the trailing `'` escaped with a backslash, this has left the string literal open. The next `'` character in the query will end the string, leaving whatever follows in raw SQL content. If you can inject there, the query is vulnerable.

This problem only applies to a few East Asian encodings like Shift-JIS where multibyte sequences can contain bytes which on their own are valid ASCII characters like the backslash. If the mismatched encodings both treat low bytes as always-ASCII (strict ASCII supersets like the more-common mismatch of Latin-1 vs UTF-8), no such confusion is possible.

Luckily servers which default to these encodings are uncommon, so in practice this is a rarely-exploitable issue. But if you *have* to use `mysql_real_escape_string` you should do it right. (Better to avoid it completely by using parameterised queries though.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [secure your applications against SQL injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide), you should be using **prepared statements** and not escaping your input. (Don't let MySQLi or PDO emulate prepares, either; use real prepared statements if you can!)

Only for situations where you can't use prepared statements should escaping ever be considered (dynamically generated queries, `LIMIT`). In these specific instances, make sure you're not [making `mysqli_real_escape_string()` bypassable because of misconfigured character sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2224584). (This linked StackOverflow answer by ircmaxell explains the problem better than I ever could.)

WordPress recently had a problem where multibyte characters could bypass their SQL escaping strategy and [the security team patched it under the guise of Emoji support](https://kraft.im/2015/05/how-emoji-saved-your-sites-hide).

If you're using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` you are playing with fire. Be careful that you don't get burned.